# How to scanf if there could be a char or int in the same input position

Tags: c, char, int, scanf

For example, if I have an input that looks like this : 10 3 128, but also have a second input that looks like this: 16 2 F

How can i scan these values?
I've tried reading it as a string and then trying to convert it to an int or leaving it as a char if needed.

```
fscanf(in, "%d %d %c or %d, from, to, numorhex);
```

My program is basically a numeral system converter, and i'd like to know how to scan hex characters as well as ints.

Comment: You want to read base 16 numbers? Did you read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can store everything you scanned in `int` and also as `char`.
When you want to print it after scanning. You can do it from both types.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
int main(void)
{
    char *line[] = {"10 3 128", "16 2 F", NULL};
    int  nb1;
    int  nb2;
    int  nb3;
    char letter;
    char end;


    for (size_t i = 0; line[i]; ++i) {

        if (end = EOF, sscanf(line[i], "%d %d %d%c", &nb1, &nb2, &nb3, &end) == 3 && end == EOF) {
            printf("number number number : %d %d %d\n", nb1, nb2, nb3);
        } else if (end = EOF, sscanf(line[i], "%d %d %c%c", &nb1, &nb2, &letter, &end) == 3 && end == EOF) {
            printf("number number letter : %d %d %c\n", nb1, nb2, letter);
        } else {
            printf("format line not supported : %s\n", line[i]);
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Be really warry that le "%c" will accept any character, like '1', so maybe you will want to restrict the value get in %c at something you consider a letter.